# change variable value and access the changed value after page is already loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to change the variable's value and use the changed value after the page is already loaded?
I need to do the following:

- Load the page with all user's records. [a single db query]
- User selects option [active, in-active, all]
- User exports the records to excel file
- Only records belonging to ex-users, active users, or all, should be exported based on the selected option
  I sent the drop-down's value on-change using ajax.
  And I need to run some logic like:

  ```
   if(isset($userStatus))
     {
       if($userStatus == 1)
         {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $result['name']);
         }
     }
  ```

It is not an actual code, I'm just trying to create a picture of what I intend to do. I need to do without reloading the page.
This may sound dumb, but I need some help with this.

Comment: if you want the value to stay after a page load then store it in a session

Comment: yes.. but I don't think storing value is the problem here. I am not being able to access the changed value, since the page is already loaded.... Any idea here? except having to run separate queries everytime.

Comment: You can't run php in response to user events unless you are reloading the page or navigating to a new page. You *can* manipulate the page using javascript included on you page.

Comment: I tried reloading the page once the ajax operation is successful... but the result is ghastly... plus others ain't gonna like the idea of reloading the page everytime the option is selected..... please.. no other tricks or ideas??

Comment: Seems to me that the way ahead should be a selection mechanism on the front end: Use some JavaScript/jquery filter to only make the wanted records visible.

Comment: @cars10m it is there already.. I'm using dataTable to populate the records and records are manipulated by the filter... the problem is I'm not exporting HTML table, instead records straight from db query are exported in server-side

Answer (score 0):

I agree with cars10m ...

do the filter in the client side in js/jQuery

When the page load first time, from PHP save the records to javascript array of objects.

when filter some options, save the filter to another js object,
and after every changes/search that triggered...

iterate you original js array of object (that created from PHP),
and render again or even show/hide relevant rows after you test the filters.